# Click button to add new line character

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is frustrating me.  I've tried

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDrugList.Focus();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDrugList.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            drugDiv.InnerHtml += txtDrugList.Text + " ";
            Response.Write("\n");

        }
        txtDrugList.Text = "";

    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDrugList.Focus();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDrugList.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            drugDiv.InnerHtml += txtDrugList.Text + Environment.NewLine;


        }
        txtDrugList.Text = "";

    }
}
```

and neither work.  I want to have a button click add a newline character to a div.  Why the heck isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said what you mean by "neither work" - but have you remembered that in HTML you need something like `<br />` for a visible line break?

I strongly suspect that if you look at the raw HTML you *are* including a line break - it's just that it's not doing anything to the displayed version. So I suspect you want something like:

```
if (txtDrugList.Text.Length > 0)
{
    drugDiv.InnerHtml += "<br />" + txtDrugList.Text;
}
```

Note that I've also put the line break *before* `txtDrugList.Text` - otherwise you've got a line break at the end of the HTML, which probably isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: ` drugDiv.InnerHtml += txtDrugList.Text + Environment.NewLine;
            Response.Write("<br/>");` that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I had used a StringBuilder and then Append("<br/>") and that worked.  But I can't understand why I can't write the breakline straight to the div.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: It's not clear what you actually did with the StringBuilder, to be honest. I didn't suggest using `Response.Write("<br />")` though - I was suggesting using `<br />` *instead of `Environment.NewLine`*.

Comment: It adds the strings with a space instead of a break line.  If I don't try to add the breakline then it doesn't add the space.  I'm curious why that is.

Comment: @Mr. Skeet.  That doesn't work either, it adds a space between the strings, but it doesn't add the break line

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: *What* adds the strings with a space? And what strings? You're being very unclear. (I'm about to board a flight, too, so at any minute I'll stop being able to respond.)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Fundamentally, I think you need to look at the resulting HTML (as HTML). If that's what you expect it to be but it's not rendering properly, you should experiment with just some static HTML until you've worked out what you want it to be.

Comment: Everything that should be a newline character is being intrepreted a space.  Environment.newline adds a space, not a break line.

Comment: Thanks for the time, enjoy your flight.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Why are you still using `Environment.NewLine` at all? I've said repeatedly, you should be using `<br />` - because that's how you specify a line break **in HTML**.

Comment: I was trying both, neither one of them are working.  And if I look at the source, I don't see the <br/>, just the strings sent to the div.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with such a remedial question.  I was frustrated that Response.Write("<br/>") wasn't working, and I let my impatience work against me.